# Huge delay between OPEN and BOUND events in Netty

Tags: java, netty

We are using Netty 3.6.2 to process our HTTP requests. We are viewing significant delay (35 seconds) between OPEN and BOUND events during peak hours.

We have enabled logging but there is no error in logs. Following is log for our request

```
New I/O server boss #9 INFO  2014-09-25 17:55:01,844: com.x.core.httpserver.HttpRequestListener Channel Event Received: [id: 0xbd52f223, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:46143 => /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9191] OPEN
New I/O server boss #9 DEBUG 2014-09-25 17:55:01,844: org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler [id: 0xbd52f223, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:46143 => /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9191] OPEN
New I/O worker #4 INFO  2014-09-25 17:55:36,439: com.x.core.httpserver.HttpRequestListener Channel Event Received: [id: 0xbd52f223, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:46143 => /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9191] BOUND: /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9191
New I/O worker #4 DEBUG 2014-09-25 17:55:36,439: org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler [id: 0xbd52f223, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:46143 => /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9191] BOUND: /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9191
New I/O worker #4 INFO  2014-09-25 17:55:36,439: com.x.core.httpserver.HttpRequestListener Channel Event Received: [id: 0xbd52f223, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:46143 => /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9191] CONNECTED: /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:46143
```

Please see time difference between log line #2 and #3 above. The delay between open and bound state is about 35 secs. Anybody got a clue why this may be happening?

Comment: Maybe you block the I/O thread somehow ?

Comment: Yes. We are investigating in that direction.

Comment: @NormanMaurer We are not blocking the boss thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that we were blocking the I/O thread.